# Creating a rails testing dashboard in a non-test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I want to create an online admin dashboard which will indicate whether our most important tests are passing.  I've already written the tests, but how I could run them on demand and see what their results are in a non-test (production) environment?

I'd like to avoid rewriting the test code if possible.

I have 3 ideas for how to do this (not sure if they're any good):

1. Using system calls to grep the verbose (`-v`) output of the tests
2. Use a different test_runner that will give easier to parse ouptut via system call
3. Somehow abstract the testing functions so that they can be used in a non-test context.  (Not sure how I would do this..